# Can't see files in master page folder in Sharepoint Designer 2010 but It's still there

Tags: 2010, master-page, folder, hidden

When I open SharePoint Designer 2010, and open master page folder, the folder is empty, and no files are showed. If I go to browser and check the same folder, all files are there.

How can I fix it?

Comment: could you please explain it and give more information to better understand it.

Comment: When I open Sharepoint Designer 2010, and open master page folder, the folder is empty, any file are showed. If I go to browser and check the same folder, all files are there. How can I fix it?

Comment: what permission level you have? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/3fad2d48-b1b7-4795-80ea-61f4bc9f2a38/could-not-find-masterpage-folder-using-sharepoint-designer

Comment: The highest level. With the same user I could see all the files before. I don't know what happened to change it.

Comment: I have to install all sharepoint site again to resolve it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To prevent users from customizing master pages on your SharePoint sites, you can **uncheck the Enable Customizing Master Pages and Layout Pages on one** or both of the SharePoint Designer Settings pages. When this option is disabled, users will no longer see the Master Pages or Page Layouts links in the Navigation pane of SharePoint Designer.

**SharePoint Designer settings pages**
To manage how SharePoint Designer 2010 is used in your organization, you can use one of two SharePoint Designer Settings pages:

- Central Administration > SharePoint Designer Settings
- Site Collection Administration > SharePoint Designer Settings
  [image]

check more here

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/managing-sharepoint-designer-2010-HA101838275.aspx#_Toc257189514

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/introduction-to-sharepoint-master-pages-HA102019628.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Navigate through All Files->catalogs->masterpages you would be able to see the files.

Comment: I can't see the catalog folder neither

Comment: It can be a permission issue. Check your permissions

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files at below path :

All Files -> _catalogs -> masterpage -> Display Templates -> Search